# How to insert switch result into html object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make to work code like this?

```
switch ( "test" ) {
  case "jana":
    ("Yes its Jana");
    break;
  case "marek":
    ("Its marek");
    break;

    break;
  default:
    ("<b>Something else</b>");
}
```

Switch result should append at code bellow the script. Here:

```
 $("body").append( "<p>Here is switch result:</p><b> RESULT </b>" );
```

I can't insert "$("body").append( "**appended**" );" into switch case because in my project is that part of code to long. It will make code bad readable.

So my goal is:

- 1) Find if word match variable at switch
- 2) Display case result  **RESULT**

Codepen is here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpXLXx?editors=0010

Comment: so you return the string from a function that you call or you can just use an object with keys.

Answer (score 2):

Just assign the string to a variable and then append that string to `body`:

```
var toAppend;

switch ( "test" ) {
  case "jana":
    toAppend = "Yes its Jana";
    break;
  case "marek":
    toAppend = "Its marek";
    break;
  default:
    toAppend = "<b>Something else</b>";
}

$("body").append( "<p>Here is switch result:</p><b>" + toAppend + "</b>" );
```

See [updated Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yOmKyd?editors=0010).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
function getPerson(name) {
    var result;
  switch (name) {
    case "jana":
      result = "Yes its Jana";
      break;
    case "marek":
      result = "Its marek";
      break;
    default:
      result = "<b>Something else</b>";
  }

  return result;
}
```

And then:

```
$("body").append( "<p>Here is switch result:</p><b> " +  getPerson("RESULT") + "</b>" );
```

A [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) helps in case you need to re-use this somewhere else.

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/8y0zevn7/